# Why I get a syntax error in my SSRS Report

Tags: reporting-services

Does someone know why I get this error? I have no idea what happened.

Table `Dataset`:

```
SELECT [PurchaseOrderID]
      ,[RevisionNumber]
      ,[Status]
      ,[EmployeeID]
      ,[VendorID]
      ,[ShipMethodID]
      --,[OrderDate]
      , YEAR([OrderDate]) Order_YEAR
      --,[ShipDate]
      ,[SubTotal]
      ,[TaxAmt]
      ,[Freight]
      ,[TotalDue]
      ,[ModifiedDate]
  FROM [AdventureWorks2019].[Purchasing].[PurchaseOrderHeader]
WHERE CONVERT(nvarchar(50), YEAR([OrderDate])) IN (@P2_Year)
   OR CONVERT(nvarchar(50), @P2_Year)          IN ('No options')
```

Multi-Parameter Dataset

```
IF @Ansicht = 2

   SELECT distinct YEAR([OrderDate]) as Order_YEAR
   FROM [AdventureWorks2019].[Purchasing].[PurchaseOrderHeader]
   order by 1 desc

ELSE 

   SELECT 'No options' as Order_YEAR
```

Everything looks good, but I get an weird error, but only if I choose more than one parameter value.

[image]

Same error without convert, if a select multi values. With one value its works.

```
WHERE 1 = 1
AND ( Order_YEAR in (@P2_Year) OR @P2_Year = 'No options' )
```

This is probably the problem?

```
WHERE 1 = 1
AND ( Order_YEAR in ('2022','2021') OR ('2022','2021') = 'No options' )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with your WHERE clause

```
WHERE CONVERT(nvarchar(50), YEAR([OrderDate])) IN (@P2_Year)
   OR CONVERT(nvarchar(50), @P2_Year)          IN ('No options')
```

If you pass in a single value e.g. '2023-03-17' then your clause will become

```
WHERE CONVERT(nvarchar(50), YEAR([OrderDate])) IN ('2023-03-17')
   OR CONVERT(nvarchar(50), '2023-03-17')     IN ('No options')
```

This is fine and will work correctly, however, when you select multiple values then it becomes something like this...

```
WHERE CONVERT(nvarchar(50), YEAR([OrderDate])) IN ('2023-03-17', '2023-03-16')
   OR CONVERT(nvarchar(50), '2023-03-17', '2023-03-17')     IN ('No options')
```

obviously that last line is incorrect, CONVERT sees 3 arguments being passed instead of 2, hence the error at `,`

I *think* you should just be able to do this...

```
WHERE (CONVERT(nvarchar(50), YEAR([OrderDate])) IN (@P2_Year)
   OR @P2_Year = 'No options')
```

Note: I added the additional parentheses around this as you will need them if you add any more conditions to the where clause.

Comment: I see using convert on a multi value variable is not a good idea. But without convert its still not working if I put multi values into the variable. See above.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the solution. Very weird error, I did not known that the order of the code is important too. This how it works and of course not using convert on a multi value paramter. Put "No options" before the variable.

```
WHERE 1 = 1
AND ( Order_YEAR in (@P2_Year) OR 'No options' in (@P2_Year) )
```

Comment: Sorry I should have thought of that (it was late at night!). This way is correct as the last part is being evaluated as `OR 'No options' IN ('2021', '2022')` which is valid, or when "No options" is selected it would be `OR 'No options' IN ('No options')` which is also valid.